# Get all the blog's categories and the related URLs?

Tags: categories

I'm confused as to how to fetch the list of all the blog's categories (sans empty ones). I need the textual name and the URL to the cat archive as an array.

Do I use `get_terms()`, `get_categories()`, `wp_list_categories()`, `wp_query()` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_categories()` is just a wrapper for `get_terms()`, and you can use either function to get all the blog's categories which I assume are of the standard `category` taxonomy?; however, you can set a *custom taxonomy* when calling `get_categories()`, and one good reason to using `get_categories()` instead of `get_terms()` is that the output is *always* an array and not a `WP_Error` instance (even if `get_terms()` returned that instance).

[`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) is a higher level function which displays/echoes or retrieves the HTML list of categories, and the function uses `get_categories()` to get the categories list.

So if you want to get an array of the categories' name and (archive page) URL, then you'd want to use either `get_categories()` or `get_terms()`, but not `wp_list_categories()`.

Here's an example using `get_categories()` and [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) to get the category page's URL:

```php
$cats = get_categories( 'hide_empty=0' );
if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
        $url = get_category_link( $term );
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

For the full list of accepted/supported parameters, see [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) for `get_categories()`, which actually points you to [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).